# CSS overlay not appearing over <img>?

Tags: css, hover

The main structure I'm using is:

```
<div class="portfolio-thumbs">
    <div class="col-md-4 thumb-item">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="thumb-img">
                <img src="./img/portfolio/rocksea.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <div class="thumb-overlay"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
   ...
</div>
```

I've created a full JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/breadadams/w5zghtjs/)

I'm looking to add a semi-transparent overlay to the image (will later be adding transition and some content to slide in from bottom of each image), yet can't seem to get it to appear.

Have compared to couple of other articles on SO but none seemed to fit the bill.

I've done this a thousand times before, any idea what's going wrong with this?

Comment: If you inspect element you can see that `.thumb-overlay` has a height of 0 because its parent doesn't have a set height. Either you need to set a fixed height somewhere or use percent going all the way up the tree

Comment: I had messed with this @ZachSaucier but didn't seem to make much difference. I've updated the fiddle, still not seeing <div> on hover: http://jsfiddle.net/breadadams/w5zghtjs/1/

Comment: It still doesn't have a height...

Comment: All elements had 100% height, position of overlay needed sorting, see my answer below. Thanks for your help @ZachSaucier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of @ZachSaucier , adding 100% height to all elements in tree. Also adding:

```
div.latest-work div.portfolio-thumbs div.thumb-item a div.thumb-img div.thumb-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Made the overlay sit on top of the img.

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/breadadams/w5zghtjs/3/)